# Запятая между «но» и «когда»

Tags: пунктуация

*Конечно, это было глупо, и, конечно, я не сумел вывернуться, но когда я стал подходить к баронессе, помню, меня самого как будто что-то подзадорило, именно школьничество подзадорило.*
[Достоевский. Игрок]

В книге нет запятой между «но» и «когда». Погуглив на эту тему, пришёл к выводу, что она нужна. Так нужна или нет?

Comment: Что-то может быть между чем-то и чем-то только.

Comment: @Aer: я вам в чат написал позавчера, ответите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Конечно, это было глупо, и, конечно, я не сумел вывернуться, но **когда я стал подходить к баронессе**, помню, меня самого как будто что-то подзадорило, именно школьничество подзадорило.*

По общему правилу запятая на стыке двух союзов ставится, если придаточное **можно переместить** и расположить после главного, и не ставится, если этого сделать нельзя (например, при наличии двойных союзов вида КОГДА...ТО).

Однако в данном случае такая перестановка затруднительна в связи **с распространенностью главного предложения**, поэтому союз НО относится ко всему СПП (запятая не ставится).

Answer (score 1):

Запятой может и не быть.
Розенталь, § 36:

> 3) после союза *но* запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и
>   не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.:
>
> > Но, если далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку (Сим.);
> >
> > Но когда он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);